# Probability - Limits of integration for Z=X+Y, with bivariate density f(x,y)

Tags: probability-distributions

It is given that 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
   864(2x-y)(y-x), & x \le y\le 2x, x+y \le 1\\
   0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Find the density $f_z(z)$ for $Z=X+Y$

I have used the formula for convolution that says

$$f_z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,x-z) \, dx$$

The problem is i have no idea which limits to use on the integral. According to the solution, we have that $ z/3\leq x\leq z/2$ and $z \in [0,1]$

Anyone who could explain to me how these limits are found?

Comment: you should have $$f_Z(z) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z-x) dx$$

Comment: You should have $f_Z(z)$, not $f_z(z)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $\displaystyle f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \, dx$, not the version with $x-z$. The point here is that in the expression $(x,z-x)$ the sum of the $x$ and $y$ components should be $z$, so the point $(x,y)$ moves along the line $x+y=z$ with $z$ constant.

For any fixed value of $z$, consider the line $x+y=z$.  This line has slope $-1$ in the $(x,y)$-plane.  It intersects the line $y=2x$ at $(x,y)=(z/3,\,2z/3)$ and it intersects the line $y=x$ at $(x,y)=(z/2,\,z/2)$.

Comment: I was using the right integral, just misswrote in my question, my bad!

How exactly do you determine where z intersects with y?

Comment: Say for example $z=5$.  Then the line $x+y=z$ is the line $x+y=5$.  You need the intersection of $x+y=5$ with $y=2x$.  If $y=2x$ then $2x$ can be put in place of $y$ in the other equation, getting $x+2x=5$.  That gives us $3x=5$, so $x=5/3$.  If $x=5/3$ then $y=2x=10/3$.  With some other number $z$ rather than $5$, instead of $5/3$ we have $z/3$.  Similarly for the intersection of $y=x$ with $x+y=5$. ${}\qquad{}$